# How to transpose/separate list elements into panda data frame columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert my output into a pandas data frame and I am struggling. I have this list which I obtain by reading multiple CSV files and reading a specific row and columns `dfs = [(pd.read_csv(f,sep="\t",header = 1,engine='python').iloc[[6,7],[1]]) for f in files]`. each comma is separating the values i had gotten from one file.

```
[   3.08945e+09  
6    1825150.0
7    7746660.0,
3.14925e+09
6    2171520.0
7    6356880.0,
3.00826e+09
6    2344600.0
7    7881130.0,]
```

[Screenshot of the code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MQoV.png)

How do I convert this into a three-column dataset? like below.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
3.08945e+09 1825150.0 7746660.0
3.14925e+09 2171520.0 6356880.0
3.00826e+09 2344600.0 7881130.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html). If your list is `k`:

```
>>> k

[   3.08945e+09
 6    1825150.0
 7    7746660.0,
    3.14925e+09
 6    2171520.0
 7    6356880.0,
    3.00826e+09
 6    2344600.0
 7    7881130.0]

>>> pd.concat(k, axis=1).T.reset_index()
         index          6          7
0  3.08945e+09  1825150.0  7746660.0
1  3.14925e+09  2171520.0  6356880.0
2  3.00826e+09  2344600.0  7881130.0
```

If you don't want the index, add `drop=True` to `reset_index`:

```
>>> pd.concat(lst, axis=1).T
 
           6          7
0  1825150.0  7746660.0
1  2171520.0  6356880.0
2  2344600.0  7881130.0
```

**NOTE:** Next time you ask a question, try to include the code as text, not image.

Comment: Awesome. It worked. However, I would like to further ask if its possible to not have row index in the data? as you can see, I am reading only 6, 7 row and its adding its index alongside in the output.

Comment: No, it didn't really work. it instead converted the first column into the index column now.

Comment: what i meant to ask was if its possible to not have the index column as output from pd.read_csv code i am using.

Comment: I see, I misunderstood your question, check now.

Comment: Also, if you would like to not read index while reading the dataframe, instead of `.iloc[[6,7], [1]]`, use `.iloc[[6,7], 1]`. Then you would not need `reset_index` after `concat`.

Comment: I guess, I am still explaining myself wrong, my data has 3 columns,  

3.08945e+09  1825150.0  7746660.0, 
with drop=True, it is simply eliminating my first column from the data

Comment: Please update desired output in the question.